# jQuery equivalent for css selector progress::-webkit-progress-value

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector, css-transitions, progress

I need to adjust the transition time for a HTML5 `<progress>`-Bar with JS (jQuery) but I cannot find the right selector in jQuery doing this.

My current tries:

`CSS`:

```
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s; /* Works like a charm */
}
```

`JavaScript` (with no success):

```
// These lines do nothing when the progress value changes:
$(".progressSelectorClass[progress-value]").css({"-webkit-transition" : "all 6s"}); 
$(".progressSelectorClass > *").css({"-webkit-transition" : "all 6s"}); 
$(".progressSelectorClass").css({"-webkit-transition" : "all 6s"});

// This gets an error:
$(".progressSelectorClass::-webkit-progress-value").css({"-webkit-transition" : "all 6s"});
```

Is there any chance to select the `progress::-webkit-progress-value` in JavaScript (with or without jQuery)?

In this jsFiddle you will see more clearly what I try to do:
http://jsfiddle.net/rD5Mc/1/

***Update:***

*I got the effect with an ugly workaround by adding/change a `data-animation-time` parameter to the `<progress>`-element and created several css-classes like this:*

```
progress[data-animation-time="5"]::-webkit-progress-value { -webkit-transition: all 5s; }
progress[data-animation-time="10"]::-webkit-progress-value {    -webkit-transition: all 10s;    }
progress[data-animation-time="15"]::-webkit-progress-value {    -webkit-transition: all 15s;    }
progress[data-animation-time="20"]::-webkit-progress-value {    -webkit-transition: all 20s;    }
progress[data-animation-time="25"]::-webkit-progress-value {    -webkit-transition: all 25s;    }
...
```

*It works, but I'm very unhappy with my solution. There must be a better way...*

Comment: You should set a jsFiddle i think

Comment: @roasted I can do it, but where is the sense with a non-working selector?

Comment: @godesign Did the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the javascript to modify the css rules!

```
var rule;

$(".animationtimeFirst").change(function() {
    time = $(this).val();


    // Write out out full CSS selector + declaration
    s = '.progressselector::-webkit-progress-value { -webkit-transition: all ' + time + 's; }';

    // Check the rules
    // If there's no rules,
    if ((!rule && rule !== 0) || !document.styleSheets[0].cssRules.length) {
        // Make one! -- Insert our CSS string into the page stylesheet
        rule = document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(s, 0);
        // I think this code is different in IE, beware!
        console.log('Our rule is #' + rule);
    } else {
    // If we already have a rule we can change the style we've implement for the psuedo class
    document.styleSheets[0].rules[rule].style.webkitTransitionDuration = time.toString() + 's';
    }
});
```

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/trolleymusic/MHYY8/3/ -- hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks for the answer, had some troubles to implement it into my mobile application but it gave me the right input to solve it more dynamically. I've used the a single line code like `$("head").append("<style>...</style>");` and remove it before I update the selector. So I give you the bounty for your effort and because I've learned something new from your answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

`progress::-webkit-progress-value` is not a DOM-Element (it's part of the Shadow DOM, though). So you cannot acccess it with jQuery or any DOM method.

It all comes down to a workaround like yours.

**EDIT:**

It turns out that in recent versions of Chrome you actually can access the Shadow DOM with the `webkitShadowRoot` property. Unfortunately it does not work for the `<progress />` element.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to only change the color of the bar from js and everything else would stay static. This is a solution for that specific scenario. This method cannot be used to change anything other than the color.

I just set the background color to `currentColor` (which matches whatever `color` is set to on that element).

```css
.progressbar-class::-webkit-progress-value 
{
    background-color: currentColor;
    /* set anything else that won't change */
}
```

This means you can select the progress bar element itself using jQuery or anything else and set it's color:

```js
$(".progressbar-class").css("color", "red");
```